# Add custom field to kubernetes resource

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to add a custom field to a kubernetes resource (without creating a CRD)?

I want to create a secret but add a custom field like an ID what is not used by k8s but from another application.

When I add the field in metadata or just at the beginning, `kubectl apply` fails with

> error validating data: [ValidationError(Secret): unknown field "custom_field" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Secret

Comment: You can add custom labels to resources.

Answer (score 3):

No. There's a schema to comply with, depending on which object you work with. Most of the time, you would not be able to add arbitrary keys like this.

A way to add custom IDs to native Kubernetes resources may be to use some annotation (or label):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  annotations:
    example.com/custom-field: my-value
  name: foo
....
```

Comment: Actually, I could turn of the validity and then it worked for my cases ... do you have an example of a resource where it does not work because you write "depending which object"?

Comment: any object with a loosely defined schema. Like this: https://github.com/search?q=x-kubernetes-preserve-unknown-fields&type=code